# Estimating bias on dynamic panel for fixed effects estimators

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, stata, bias, fixed-effects-model

I need to replicate the following table using Stata:

[image]

I generate $\mu$, $v$ and $y_0$ as $(N(0,1))$ for each T. 
Then I generate $y=\alpha*L.y+\mu+v$.
I run "xtreg y L.y, fe", calculate the bias, and simulate this for 1000 replications.

For some reason, I am able to get the same results as presented in the table for $\alpha=0, 0.1, 0.25, 05$. But for larger alphas, the bias becomes smaller: for $\alpha=0.9$ I get a bias of $-0.073$, for $\alpha=0.95$, $-0.056$ and for $\alpha=0.99$ $-0.040$.

Any ideas for why this could happen? I am using an $N=10,000$, and I have tried with other N and I still get the same result.

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose $\mu$ is the fixed effect, which should be the same for $t=1,\ldots,T$. Do you do that?

Comment: Yes I did, I generated a $\mu$ for each $i$ which is the same for every $t$